# Make each option in a select list a hyperlink to a different page

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make every word from my select list a hyperlink to another page?

When the `leaderboard` select is dynamically populated with options (per the code below), I want to make options clickable and have them redirect to a specified page.

```
<select id='standings' name='standings' onchange="listTeam(this)">
    <option value='0'>A</option>
    <option value='1'>B</option>
    <option value='2'>C</option>
    <option value='3'>D</option>
</select>

<select id='leaderBoard' name='leaderBoard' multiple="multiple" size="1" style="width: 100px;"> </select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var teams = [
                "x y z ",
                "e r t z u ",
                "w e r t",
            ],

            listTeam = function listTeam(sel) {
                var val = document.getElementById('standings').value, //get the selected value
                        team = teams[val], //get the selected team, based on value
                        lb = document.getElementById('leaderBoard'); //get the leaderBoard select element

                lb.options.length = 0;

                var people = team.trim().split(/\s/);
                for (var j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option')
                    opt.innerText = people[j];
                    lb.appendChild(opt);
                }
            };
    listTeam();

</script>
```

Comment: `select`s can't contain anchors (hyperlinks).  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: " how can I every word from my select" I think you accidentally a word.

Comment: var teams = ["x y z ",
              "e r t z u ", "w e r t", ...... I want for Example "x" is a hyperlink to another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested with A only would need to change array etc to work with the rest, set urls inside of the 'value=' on the `<option>`, on selection redirects window location

```
   var teams = [
       "x y z ",
       "e r t z u ",
       "w e r t", ];

   var urls = ["www.a.com", "www.a1.com", "www.a2.com"];

   listTeam = function listTeam(sel) {
       var val = document.getElementById('standings').value, //get the selected value
           team = teams[val], //get the selected team, based on value
           lb = document.getElementById('leaderBoard'); //get the leaderBoard select
       lb.options.length = 0;

       var people = team.trim().split(/\s/);

       for (var j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
           var opt = document.createElement('option')
           opt.value = urls[j];
           opt.innerText = people[j];
           lb.appendChild(opt);
       }

       lb.onchange = function () {
           console.log("change");
           if (this.selectedIndex) {
               window.location.href = this.value;
           }
       }
   };
   listTeam();
```

html

```
<select id='standings' name='standings' onchange="listTeam(this)">
    <option value='0'>A</option>
    <option value='1'>B</option>
    <option value='2'>C</option>
    <option value='3'>D</option>
</select>
<select id='leaderBoard' name='leaderBoard' multiple="multiple" size="1" style="width: 100px;">
```